# how to set custom hiddenclass function in pybrain?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, pybrain

I want to train a neural network with  (1,Nh,1,1) (one input, Nh neurons in the first hidden layer , 1 neuron in the second hidden layer and 1 output).

In the second hidden layer I would like to use a custom function.

Is there any easy way to do that? 
I am using pybrain.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You will need to implement your own layer derived from NeuronLayer with your custom Forward and Backward logic. Something like:

```
from pybrain.structure.modules.neuronlayer import NeuronLayer

class CustomLayer(NeuronLayer):
"""Layer implementing the custom function."""

def _forwardImplementation(self, inbuf, outbuf):
    outbuf[:] = custom_func_fwd(inbuf)

def _backwardImplementation(self, outerr, inerr, outbuf, inbuf):
    inerr[:] = custom_func_bkwd(outbuf,outerr)
```